# Swap positons on two lists stored in tuple

Tags: python, data-structures, tuples, assign

I have a tuple that includes a number of lists and I need to dynamically swap the values of the items in two lists. For example, `tuple_of_lists = (**list1**:[1,1,1],list2:[2,2,2],**list3**:[3,3,3])` I need to be able to input `--swap x & y (1,3)--` and without changing the names of the lists, have an output of (`**list1**:[3,3,3],list2:[2,2,2],**list3**:[1,1,1]`)

still very new to python (and coding in general) and think I'm missing something about the data structure.

I am trying to use something like :

```
intermediary = tuple_of_lists[1] 
tuple_of_lists[1] = list(tuple_of_lists[3]) 
tuple_of_lists[3] = list(intermediary)
```

but I am getting an error that tuple does not accept assignment--even though it is only list that are actually being changed? Is there an easy way to solve?

Comment: `list_of_lists = list(tuple_of_lists)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are immutable, so you cannot change their element. Lists, however, are mutable.

What you could do is create a list from your tuple, swap the elements and convert the list back to a tuple:

```
tuple_of_lists = ([1,1,1], [2,2,2], [3,3,3])
lt =  list(tuple_of_lists)                    #create list from tuple
lt[2],lt[0] = lt[0],lt[2]                     #swap items 0 and 2
tuple_of_lists = tuple(lt)                    #convert to tuple

print(tuple_of_lists)
```

Output:

```
([3,3,3], [2,2,2], [1,1,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

## Why are you getting a `TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment`?

Tuples are immutable in python. It means that once created/initialized, you cannot change their content. So, tuples cannot be on the left side of an assignment operator and hence the error.

## Solution:

A possible solution is to change the lists in place instead of changing the reference to the list stored in the tuple. Consider this example code,

```py
a_tuple = ([1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3])
x = 1
y = 3
# We'll use x-1 and y-1 for 0-based indexing
temp = a_tuple[x-1].copy() # Keep a copy in temporary variable
a_tuple[x-1].clear() # Empty first list
a_tuple[x-1].extend(a_tuple[y-1]) # Fill it with second list
a_tuple[y-1].clear() # Empty second list
a_tuple[y-1].extend(temp) # Fill it with first list

print(a_tuple)
```

---

Output

```py
([3, 3, 3], [2, 2, 2], [1, 1, 1])
```

Comment: I appreciate the response.